# Facebook Photo Upload iPhone Integration Issue

Tags: iphone, facebook, upload, photo

I am using FacebookAgent by Amanapps. It is a nice little wrapper for Facebook integration in iPhone apps. So far everything is peachy. But I noticed that when I upload a photo to my account, Facebook does not automatically publish it to the wall, instead Facebook puts it on hold and I need to goto See All Photos and approve them first.

Is there any way I can bypass this "approval" method. I feel it is ridiculous since upon logging in, the user has already give consent to the "app" to post the photo.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, anyway, I had to move away from FacebookAgent since in latest FB SDK, FacebookAgent is no longer updated. I ended up coding my own Facebook usage in the app using latest SDK with SSO. I even wrote a tutorial for it, for those who'd like to know how to do it please visit: http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-upload-photo-and-update-status.html

Thanks.